# Do i have to download or link jqueytools in ruby on rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript, jquery-tools

do i have to link the jquerytools js or download it, or is there a better possibility with coffeescript, like 
      //= require jquery.tools.min.js
or sth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery tools must be downloaded or the site must link to a jquerytools lib and then one can simply add:
//= require jquery.tools.min.js to